# What is the best way to receive array response from php page using jquery-ajax-json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

What I am trying to do:
I have a html form in a page "add.php" with some jquery code which sends the user inputs to a "save.php" using serialize() function.
Now upon success or failure in the "save.php" file, I want to receive an array response in the caller page "add.php" and display that somewhere in the page using jquery.

What I tried so far:
I can send POST data to "save.php" and receive single response from it using serialize() function and jquery ajax.
But I am unable to receive an array response from "save.php" using either xml or json.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.notification').hide();

  $('.submit').click(function(){
    var check=0;
    console.log($('#requestForm').serialize());

    if(check == 0){
      $.ajax({
        url:  "save.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: $('#requestForm').serialize(),
        statusCode: {404: function() {alert('page not found');}
                    },
        success: function(data){
          alert("works"+data);
          // alert(data["alert_type"]);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="requestForm" method="post" action="save.php">
   <input type="text" name="txt_code" id="txt_code" placeholder="Customer Code"/>
   <input type="text" name="txt_name" id="txt_name" placeholder="Customer Name"/>
   <input type="text" name="txt_searchname" id="txt_searchname" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Name (24)"/>
  <button type="button" class="submit">Send Request</button>
</form>
```

Please please help me find a solution for this. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not returning json from your php function ?

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>

//The above example will output:

{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Comment: Thanks. But serialize() function is not working if I mention the data type as json.

Comment: indeed, serialize() creates a "text string in standard URL-encoded notation", not json.   -- But if your question is about receiving the response as json, you dont need to post the request with json. You could post with serialize(), so remove the json data-type, and send your data in the response from your php in json as i mentionned before : json_encode($arr);